# Image Disappears When Re-sizing In CSS

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I am a graphic designer trying to code a website. I am stuck on the homepage and have been for weeks. My problem is that I can't get an image to re-size with CSS because it disappears or gets cut off. Here is what I am trying to [do](http://i61.tinypic.com/sc7xhk.jpg)

Here is my code:

```css
#wrapper {
        position: relative;
}

#wrapper > div {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 960px;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
}

#wrapper > div#home {
        width: 291px;
        height: 290px;
        position: absolute;
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* Safari */
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#wrapper > div#contact {
        width: 291px;
        height: 290px;
        position: absolute;
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* Safari */
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        margin-left: -150px;
        margin-top: 180px;
        
}

#wrapper > div#contact img {
        width: 60%;
        height: auto;
        
}
```

But with that code I get [this](http://i60.tinypic.com/90wqv8.png)

If you look at the contactbttn (Phone icon) you can see the glowing edge is cut off.

Comment: your tinypic images are not working for me :(

Comment: Here try these: 1st link: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=83975171309583950670 and Second link: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=02079782100105957230

Comment: second link? try creating a fiddle instead: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will remove `overflow: hidden;` from `#wrapper > div` then your image will not be cutted off. All the other things are up to you, because I also can't see what we are dealing with.

Comment: YOU SAVED ME! This actually worked! I was so blind to that. As to not being able to see what was happening to anyone in the future look at the links in my reply to David Anderton's comment.